# Rails 3 + PostgreSQL + RSpec: App works fine but RSpec example fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rspec

I am developing this Rails 3.2 application using the Apartment gem as middleware. The application itself works perfectly and all the RSpec examples also work perfectly when ran individually. However, when I run all the tests at the same time using the `bundle exec rspec` command, there are two examples that fail in two different controller specs and they do exactly the same thing. Here are the two examples in question:

In the `issues_controller_spec.rb` file:

```
describe "GET 'new'" do

  # ...

  context "for authenticated users" do
    before(:each) do
      controller.log_in(create(:user))
      get :new
    end

    # ...

    it "should create a new issue instance and put it in an instance variable" do
      assigns(:issue).should be_an_instance_of Issue
    end
  end
end
```

In the `users_controller_spec.rb` file:

```
describe "GET 'new'" do

    # ...

  context "for authenticated users" do

      # ...

    context "for admin users" do
      before(:each) do
        admin = create(:admin)
        admin.add_role :admin
        controller.log_in(admin)
        get :new
      end

      # ...

      it "should create a new User instance and put it in an instance variable" do
        assigns(:user).should be_an_instance_of User
      end
    end
  end
end
```

These two examples are affected by a before hook:

```
before(:each) do
  client = create(:client)
  @request.host = "#{client.account_name}.lvh.me"
end
```

When creating a new Client, there is an `after_create` callback:

```
# Create the client database (Apartment) for multi-tenancy
def create_client_database
  begin
    Apartment::Database.create(self.account_name)
  rescue Apartment::SchemaExists
    return
  rescue
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

And there is where the examples fail. Now if I remove the `begin...rescue...end` block and keep the line `Apartment::Database.create(self.account_name)` I get the following exception in the failling examples:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
   : SET search_path TO public
```

Again, if I run the examples individually, they pass but if I run all the examples, the two examples above fail.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong please?

**Note**: The whole application code can be found [here](https://github.com/AzizLight/AgileBaboon/tree/rolify).

Comment: where are you actually calling your controller actions?

Comment: @Karpie in another [before hook](https://github.com/AzizLight/AgileBaboon/blob/rolify/spec/controllers/issues_controller_spec.rb#L84), but it doesn't matter because the examples fail before that (in the first before filter, where the client is created)

Comment: we dont get to see the code that calls the action, we don't get to see the error, what do we get to see that's actually helpful?

Comment: I updated the question with the code you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by wrapping the line `client = create(:client)` in a `begin`, `rescue`, `end` block like so:

```
before(:each) do
  begin
    client = create(:client)
  rescue
    client = Client.create!(attributes_for(:client))
  end

  @request.host = "#{client.account_name}.lvh.me"
end
```

I don't know how or why this works but I know it works.